# How can I require file from the parent project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

The project 'a' has npm dependency of package 'b'. In b's source code, I would like to do something like this:

```js
import data from './data.json'
```

and `data.json` is located in a's project directory. Currently the line above is looking for the file inside the b's file tree.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: ```import data from '../data.json'```? It would help if you included the directory structure

Comment: Project a needs to export the json content in one of the scripts so that it can be imported by project b.

Comment: project b has no idea of project a. Assume b as a library that parses json file. and project a depends on that package. However by configuration package b assumes that file is in projects root and its called `data.json`

Comment: @yudhiesh a and b are separate npm packages. A has B in package.json

Comment: If the sub-project is designed to be re-usable and not have specific knowledge of the parent project, then the parent project should pass it a path to the JSON file as part of initializing the sub-project.  If the sub-project is a built-in part of the parent project and is not separately useable, then it can just directly access the JSON file in the parent with `../data.json` from the parent's directory.

Comment: @jfriend00 appreciated. it's designed to be re-usable by different project, however It assumes a folder structure for the parent project. Unfortunately, b has many small function that rely on data.json and a can't pass the data everytime it calls one of those functions, so that's what im trying to achieve. unfortunately, I can't get `../data.json` to work

Comment: If you're going to use `../data.json`, then you have to combine it with __dirname as in `path.join(__dirname, '../data.json')`.  That will look for a file one level up from your current module's directory.  If that isn't correct, then you need to add the exact file hierarchy to your question.

Comment: When I said pass the path to `data.json` into your module, I meant to pass it ONCE at module initialization time so then every function in that module can use that path from then on without passing it with any of those functions.  You're essentially establishing a configuration for the module provided by the parent.   That is not uncommon for a reusable module that doesn't want to have hard-coded assumptions about its environment.